# How to remove webRequest.onCompleted listener in electron

Tags: electron, listener, webrequest

I don't understand how to remove the listener from webRequest.onCompleted when it's no longer needed.

In my case, I'm trying to create a function in my main process that can be called once and retrieve a value from the url in a request, then return it, and I need to delete this listener because I no longer need it. And let me create an error message in some cases.

Here's my function in the main process.

```
ipcMain.on('retrive-string', (_event, sessionId) => {
    const filter = {
      urls: ['https://google.com/api/*']
    }

    session.fromPartition('persist:' + sessionId).webRequest.onCompleted(filter, (details) => {
      mainWindow.webContents.send('string-id', details.url.split('#')[1])
    })
    
  })
```

I've tried using removeListener and removeAllListener but the listener keeps listening.